# Files lost by encfs

Tags: files, encryption, data-recovery, encfs

I recently used the software encfs in my ubuntu 18.04 laptop. I created a new stash using the same software in my desktop. I would like to list the steps....

- I created a new stash (using green plus) in my desktop with same name (Desktop) and a password.
- The newly mounted folder (looked like a drive) hadn't any folder or files.
- Later I removed the stash using the option (red minus) in encfs.
- I thought it would only remove the newly created empty folder.
- Accidentally, I lost my desktop folder (with entire files in it).
- Then home folder acts like the desktop.
- I searched in home for lost files, but found none.
- It didn't affect any files in home folder other than desktop.

Kindly please help me to retrieve my lost files. How can I retrieve them? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You say "same software". Same as what, what is this software? `encfs` has no red/green plus/minus. You seem to be referring to some GUI software.